# how to find number of pages and number of lines on the current page respect to speed after a specified interval of time?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

A student has created a software which will read from one book and write into another book . Both books may have different dimensions.
Software first reads from the book fully then process the format to write into another book.
Yours task is to identify after a specified interval of time , if software is reading or writing. for each of these activities how much read and write activity has happened needs to be captured in terms of page and number of lines on the current page.

**Input**

```
pn1 -> number of pages in first book 
ln1 -> number of lines per page in first book
pn2 -> number of pages in second book
ln2 -> number of lines per pages in second book
rs -> reading speed in lines/seconds
ws -> writing speed in lines/seconds
t -> time in seconds at which the result is to be processed
```

**Output**

```
print current activity (READ or WRITE),page number and line number
```

**Example**

```
Input
100
10
500
6
8
4
145

Output
WRITE 13 2
```

**Code :**

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pn1 = sc.nextInt();
        int ln1 = sc.nextInt();
        int pn2 = sc.nextInt();
        int ln2 = sc.nextInt();
        int rs = sc.nextInt();
        int ws = sc.nextInt();
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int i,j,s1,s2,s3=0;
        s1 = pn1 * ln1;
        s2 = s1/rs;
        if(s2<t)
        {
            System.out.print("WRITE ");
            for(i=1;i<=pn2;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=ln2;j=j+ws)
                {
                    if(s2==t)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    s2++;
                }
                if(j<=ln2)
                {
                    System.out.print(i+ " " +j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("READ ");
            for(i=1;i<=pn1;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=ln1;j=j+rs)
                {
                    if(s3==t)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    s3++;
                }
                if(j<=ln1)
                {
                    System.out.print(i+ " " +j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My output : WRITE 11 1**

Can anyone please help where I m going wrong , Because in my if else statement j value is not incrementing it will always print 1 as it will be initialized as 1 in for loop .
Thank you in advanced .

Comment: Why the response for the given data is `WRITE 13 2`?  It takes 125 s to read 1000 lines of the first book, for remaining 20 s (145 - 125) 80 lines are written at speed 6 lines/s, thus 13 pages are completely written, but the current page number is 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations in the nested loops are incorrect because they do not take into account the case when the page is not processed completely within a second.

For the input data, the writing process is as follows:
sec 1: total lines  4: page 1, line 4
sec 2: total lines  8: page 2, line 2
sec 3: total lines 12: page 2, line 6
etc.

Thus, it's better to have a single loop by the time parameter and modify the page/line information using modulo operation:

```java
if(s2<t) {
    for (int tt = s2 + 1; tt <= t; tt++) {
        j += ws;
        if (j >= ln2) {
            i++;
            j = j % ln2;
        }
    }
    if (j == 0) { // correct page number if it's been completely written within a second
        i--;
        j = ln2;
    }
    System.out.print("WRITE " + i + " " + j);
} else { // fix reading in similar way
    for (int tt = 0; tt < t; tt++) {
        j += rs;
        if (j >= ln1) {
            i++;
            j = j % ln1;
        }
    }
    if (j == 0) { // correct page number if it's been completely read within a second
        i--;
        j = ln1;
    }
    System.out.print("READ " + i + " " + j);
}
```

---

This task could also be resolved without loops using modulo arithmetics and a separate function to define current page and line:

```java
// reusing all the variables defined in main 
int totalReadLines = pn1 * ln1;
int timeToRead = (int) Math.ceil(totalReadLines / rs);
if (t <= timeToRead) {
    printState("READ", totalReadLines, rs, t, ln1);
} else {
    t -= timeToRead;
    int totalWriteLines = pn2 * ln2;
    int timeToWrite = (int) Math.ceil(totalWriteLines / ws);
    if (t <= timeToWrite) {
        printState("WRITE", totalWriteLines, ws, t, ln2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

```java
private static void printState(String state, int totalLines, int speed, int time, int linesPerPage) {
    int linesProcessed = time * speed;
    int pagesProcessed = linesProcessed / linesPerPage;
        
    int remLines = linesProcessed % linesPerPage;
        
    int currentPage;
    int currentLine;
        
    if (remLines == 0) {
        currentPage = pagesProcessed;
        currentLine = linesPerPage;
    } else {
        currentPage = pagesProcessed + 1;
        currentLine = remLines;
    }
    System.out.printf("%s %d %d%n", state, currentPage, currentLine);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , You gave me best solution for my problem.